# What is correct: "Ich habe wenig Zeit" or "Ich habe wenige Zeit"?

Tags: adjective-ending

What is right between

> Ich habe wenig Zeit

or

> Ich habe wenige Zeit?

Are both possible maybe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only the first one is correct:

> Ich habe wenig Zeit.

"Wenige Zeit" is only possible, if preceded by the definite article: "*Die* wenige Zeit, die ich habe, will ich sinnvoll nutzen."

Comment: Ok. Aber ist das richtig dann ? "Ich habe keinE Zeit?"

Comment: Und nicht "Ich habe kein Zeit"

Comment: Yes. "Ich habe keine Zeit" is correct (and "Ich habe kein Zeit" is wrong).

Comment: You might want to add that in some dialects (hence in spoken form) the "ne" is sometimes omitted, which means you might *hear* "kei' Zeit". doesn't make it *correct*, though.

Answer (score 7):

*Wenig* (and also *viel*) is a bit of a nasty adjective. See the following examples:

> Ich habe *wenig* Zeit, deswegen schreibe ich nur *wenige* Sätze.
>   Ich habe nur *wenig* Geld übrig, deswegen kann ich mir nur *wenig* warmes Essen kaufen.
>   Das *wenige* Geld muss ich zur Seite legen.
>   Die *wenigen* Leute, die den Grund dafür wissen, werden sicherlich *wenige* Informationen preisgeben.

As you can maybe see, the general rule is:

- If the noun to follow *wenig* is countable, use the plural and inflect *wenig*.
- If the noun to follow *wenig* is uncountable:

  - and there is a **definite** article, use the singular and inflect it (using the weak forms).
  - and there is no article, use the uninflected form.

This can also be found on [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Unbestimmt.html#Anchor-Unflektierte-49575).

Comment: Aber: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wenige+zeit+später%22&lr=lang_de&safe=off&biw=1162&bih=776&tbs=lr:lang_1de&tbm=bks&ei=qck8VdnHJtHtavOvgfgP&start=0&sa=N

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Hmm, ich bin mir nicht sicher, wie genau ich das einsortieren soll. Durch das *später* wird die ganze Konstruktion ja zu einer Adverbiale der Zeit … etwas anderes als wenn wenig + Substantiv als Subjekt oder Objekt dient. Vielleicht sollte ich das so einarbeiten …?