# "wenig" als Adjektiv oder Adverb

Tags: difference, learning

Welcher Satz ist richtig:

> Es hat wenig Kalorien.

oder

> Es hat wenigen Kalorien.

Comment: Auf Englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22946/35111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Der Satz

> Es hat wenig Kalorien.

ist korrekt, der zweite Satz ist falsch. Hier wird nicht [wenig als Adverb](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wenig_kaum_unbedeutend_selten) verwendet, sondern  [wenig als unbestimmtes Zahlwort](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wenig_vereinzelt_nicht_viel).