# die Komparativ-Form der Adjektivdeklination nach dem Nullartikel

Tags: adjective-ending

Ich habe diesen Vergleichssatz im Buch *Grammatik aktiv* gesehen.

> Die Ernährung in den Industriestaaten ist mit weniger Arbeit als in den Jahrhunderten zuvor verbunden.

Meine Frage ist: Warum steht hier "weniger" und nicht "wenigerer"? Ich weiß, dass das Wort nach der Präposition 'mit' im Dativ steht und hier gibt es einen Vergleich und wir haben ein feminines Wort, "Arbeit".

Comment: Das hat nichts mit dem Komparativ zu tun. Im gleichen Satz mit der Grundform von *wenig* würde es *mit wenig Arbeit* heißen, also ebenfalls ohne Endung. Siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22946/what-is-correct-ich-habe-wenig-zeit-or-ich-habe-wenige-zeit

Answer (score 1):

> Die Ernährung in den Industriestaaten ist mit weniger Arbeit als in den Jahrhunderten zuvor verbunden.

*Wenig* ist in deinem Beispiel kein Adjektiv, sondern ein Indefinitpronomen.

Der Unterschied ist oft schwer auszumachen. Am einfachsten ist es, wenn ein bestimmter Artikel davor steht, denn dieser widerspricht der Eigenschaft *indefinit*.

> Er hat wenig Geduld. — Indefinitpronomen
>
> Die wenige Geduld, die er hatte, war erschöpft. — Adjektiv

Comment: Wie passt das zum Befund, dass das Wort "wenig" in "weniger Arbeit" nicht im Positiv ("wenig Arbeit") sondern im Komparativ vorliegt. Möglich wäre auch noch der Superlativ "am wenigsten Arbeit". Ist die Fähigkeit gesteigert zu werden, nicht ein Erkennungsmerkmal von Adjektiven (und einigen wenigen Adverbien)? Wenn etwas gesteigert werden kann, kann es dann ein Pronomen sein?

Comment: Offensichtlich kann man *wenig* steigern, auch wenn es eine Menge beschreibt, also das Nomen quantifiziert statt qualifiziert. Schon mit seinem Gegenstück *viel* geht das nicht, obwohl auch dieses Adjektiveigenschaften hat. In meinem zweiten Beispiel qualifiziert *wenig* das Nomen Geduld hingegen: es handelt sich um eine Eigenschaft dieser Geduld, gering zu sein. Ich bin sogar geneigt, das Adjektiv *wenig* als synonym zum Adjektiv *gering* zu sehen.

Comment: @Janka: Auch mit seinem Gegenstück "viel" geht das: im obigen Satz kann man statt "wenig/weniger/am wenigsten" auch "viel/mehr/am meisten" einsetzen. Das ändert zwar den Sinn, aber wäre grammatikalisch genauso korrekt. Ebenso könnte man - aus grammatikalischer Sicht - jedes andere Adjektiv einsetzen: "Die Ernährung ist mit *schwererer (lustigerer, aufsehenerregenderer, ...)* Arbeit verbunden ...". Warum also "wenig" ein Indefinitpronomen sein soll, im Gegensatz zu "lustig", "schwer", etc., entzieht sich mir.

Comment: @Janka: Der (fehlende) Artikel machts übrigens nicht aus: wenige Arbeit macht mir was aus, wenig Arbeit hingegen nicht. Hingegen stört mich viel Arbeit, wenn ich mich auch mit vieler Arbeit arrangieren kann.